# GLCapabilities not importing properly in eclispe OpenGL. Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLCapabilitiesImmutable

Tags: java, opengl, importerror, jogl

### The Problem

Hi, this is probably me just being super dumb, but the GLCapabilities import isn't functioning for me.

I'm very new to OpenGL, and Java in general, so I've been following a video tutorial on the subject.

**Video Link For Episode 0: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etNPl3Dk2XY**\](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etNPl3Dk2XY**%5C)
**Video Link For Episode 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KmAZ48-M5c**

I have downloaded OpenGL and set up all the files in the project just as he goes through
in episode 0. I am using eclipse, same as him. I have also made sure to map the .jar files to the natives folder, so it can run on my OS, like described in the video.

Now at the time stamp `7:33` he launches the program, and an empty screen pops up, as it should.

BUT, for me, I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.graphics.Renderer
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/opengl/GLCapabilitiesImmutable
```

I looked at other stack overflow questions and just google searching, but I couldn't find anything specific about this.

### My Code

Here is my code for reference:

```
package org.graphics;


import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;

public class Renderer {
    
    private static GLWindow myscreen = null;
    
    public static void initalize() {
        GLProfile.initSingleton();
        
        GLProfile version = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL3);
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(version);
        
        myscreen = GLWindow.create(caps);
        
        myscreen.setSize(500,500);
        myscreen.setResizable(false);
        myscreen.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initalize();
    }
```

**Hopefully someone can help me.**

**Thanks in advance. (:**

Comment: Rather use official JogAmp tutorials, look at our wiki: https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE The simplest solution consists in adding jogamp-fat.jar into the libraries of your project in Eclipse. I have used this IDE with JOGL since 2006, don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: The correct JAR is in this 7z archive: https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20210111/archive/jogamp-fat-all.7z